# Example to combine headers footers paragraphs of html and Tables

Tags: html, css, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

jspdf-autotable examples['header-footer'] example gets me most of what I need for my task.
I am trying to add rich text (constant font some bold and under line words) before and after a table. looking at examples.content did not make it clear.

So a complete PDF might be:
1. some paragraphs of text
2. a table on more than one page
3. some paragraphs of text
4. another table on more than one page

how do I combine all of this in one `var doc = new jsPDF();` ?

Example code would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The key is to use `doc.autoTable.previous.finalY` to get the final y position where the table ended drawing. You can than dynamically use that to draw text with `doc.text()`. If you want further guidence, please update your question with more info on what you have tried and what didn't work.

Comment: This one I got. What I am missing is the sequence: once I have a doc = new jsPDF() how to prepare the headers and footers then add with doc.Text(.. doc.from html( , doc.autotabel(... , another doc.text(..) and doc.save at the end. How did not figure out if this sequence is possible.

Comment: You should just be able to call the methods after each other? I.e `doc.text("Header", 10, 10); doc.autoTable(columns, rows)`

Comment: If it was just text it would be fine :-) but I need to add some html2pdf or .fromHTML and things do not fall in line like they should

Comment: At the top of my head those methods are asynchronous. That might be your issue?